# Using multiple strings within the path to Write to Text File

Tags: c#, file-format, text

In Unity3D, How would I use something like this: `path = "C:\Users\Jonathan\Documents\FileData" + fileName + ".txt";` so I can make a for loop and create several text files under desired path?

The loop looks like this currently:

```
named = namesAsset.text.Split ('\n');
sliced = statAsset.text.Split ('\n');
for (int i = 0; i < named.Length; i++) {
    fileName = named[i].ToLower();
    path = "C:\Users\Jonathan\Documents\FileData" + fileName.Substring(1) + ".txt";
    File.WriteAllText(path, sliced[i]);
    Debug.Log (named[i]+".txt");
}
```

But there is a problem: They won't accept this! It spits out the error that the name has an invalid char.

Full script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System;

public class SplitPage : ScriptableWizard {

    public TextAsset statAsset;
    public TextAsset names;

    public string[] named = new string[151];
    public string[] sliced = new string[151];
    public string path;

    public string fileName;

    [MenuItem("GameObject/SlicePage")]
    static void CreateWizard() {
        ScriptableWizard.DisplayWizard<SplitPage>("Split Text File", "Create");
    }

    void OnWizardCreate() {
        named = names.text.Split ('\n');
        sliced = statAsset.text.Split ('\n');
        for (int i = 0; i < named.Length; i++) {
            fileName = named[i].ToLower();
            path = "C:\Users\Jonathan\Documents\FileData" + fileName.Substring(1) + ".txt";
            File.WriteAllText(path, sliced[i]);
            Debug.Log (named[i]+".txt");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You want several files with the same path? I don't get it.

Comment: Each one is SUPPOSED to change depending on what named[i] is at that point.

Comment: This is a bit confusing. Is that first code snippet meant to be part of the second one? They almost match, but not exactly.

Comment: They DO match, because that first bit was where the script goes Haywire. the 2nd is the full code.

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible to know for certain from the given code what the issue is, but a reasonable guess is that you `namesAsset` string contain DOS/Windows style line endings, and therefore when you split by `'\n'` you leave an `'\r'` at the end of strings.

I of course assume that the path you use is only a placeholder for code that reference the user folder properly.

Comment: You're right on the money. however, I only changed the \FileData\ Portion of it. So it should be, Also, It's a Unity Wizard script. so if need be, I'll edit and show the full code.